# Convert React component to Stenciljs

Tags: reactjs, stencils

For the challenge and to help me to learn Stenciljs, I want to convert some React components that a team did to Stencil ones.

I don't know React and a little bit of Stenciljs, but I know Angular. I know Stenciljs is a mix of good things from different "frameworks", so probably I will be able to understand a bit. :-)

Any advice about the component porting?

Is it feasible?

Anyone already did that kind of thing? If so, any examples or steps that could be useful would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We're going to do the same in the next weeks and it looks like it's going to be pretty easy.

We've used react together with Typescript so we already have interfaces for props and state which just have to be rewritten using decorators `@Prop()` and `@State()`.
Because in stencil you also have a `render()` function, similar to react class components, you can just copy the code of your react `render()` function (or if you've got a functional react component which basically just consists of a `render()` function, just copy everything).

One thing to note is that `{children}` in react is much more powerful than `<slot />` in stencil. So if you've got bigger components with a lot of parent/child relations, translating won't be that easy as you can't do stuff like `slot.map(item => <SomethingElse prop="stuff" />)` as far as I can see.

Comment: Hi @Schadenn, the current react components project use bootstrap-sass and they defined 4 other generic scss files (common-ux, configuration, customizations, precustomizations) where they import bootstrap-sass assets and their own ones + each component has their own scss. How can I manage that with Stencil? Does stencil-sass is enough? thanks

Comment: Depends on your .scss files:

StencilJS uses a shadow dom, so if your .scss is heavily reliant on DOM-elements and using much parent/child relations (div > h3 > span or something like that), you'll run into problems.

If the .scss is clean and only using classnames (.my-component > .my-component-child etc.), you should be fine. Just specify all your .scss files in the @Component decorator in each of your components. Stencils build process should be able to figure out all the necessary css for each component and will bundle it within the .js files that are being generated using build.

Comment: But if you're going to do a big rewrite of existing components like that, keep in mind, that it might be the perfect time to clean up your css (generally 4 big scss files extending bootstrap sounds like a bit of a bad setup), introduce a new styling or something like that.

Comment: I think I succeeded to make something. :-) Now, I need to find the equivalent for props.children and ref={this.props.ref}. Any idea by chance? :-)

Comment: props.children is similar to <slot /> - <slot /> just inserts whatever you wrote into your created component tag within your component .jsx. Problem is that you can't really do anything with <slot> - you can't .map it, cant .filter it etc. If you need operations like that you will need to access your children using document.getElementsByTagName() or something similar from your parent.

Comment: You don't really need ref. In React ref is used to get the instance of the DOM-Element. In Stencil all you create is DOM-Elements. So just get the element you need using document.getElementById() or something. In addition you can use the @Element decorator to get the HTMLElement instance of the host element of your stencil element.

Comment: Using document.get*() to get child instances can make you run into some lifecycle problems (you use it to early, children are not yet rendered etc.), so be sure where you use those. (Possibly componentDidLoad() lifecycle method is always a good spot)

Comment: Wow! Thanks @Schadenn for your help! I will do some homework to see how it goes :-)